# How to recognise a sequence of specific sounds?

Tags: signal-processing

I have a set of sound files which correspond to specific keys played by a specific piano.
If I play some of the files in a specific sequence on one device, how can I get another device to recognise the sequence ?

Keep in mind, these are not arbitrary notes being played by ANY guitar or piano or flute. These are specific files which are available on both devices - so just by listening to the audio, how can I determine the sequence of files being played?

I am open to using specific files, if it will make it easier to recognise. The goal is not to decode any kind of music or anything - its to transmit data from one device to another by playing audio files common to both device in sequence. The audio files are not anything special - I'm open to using any kind of specific audio that is easy to recognise.

I don't know anything about FFT or signal processing, but I have a lot of experience programming, so was just wondering how to get started...

EDIT: I don't care what the actual node is, I only care that if I play file "C" on the first device, I can match it with the same file on the second device.

The actual files are not user created - I'm just trying to figure out how to transmit small amounts of data using audio only. I'm open to using any sound file that can easily do the job.

EDIT: I want to transmit data between two devices using audio only - the purpose of the sound files on each device is simply to encode the data - for example if I have a set of files {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j}, perhaps each sound file could correspond to a number {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, and using that mapping I could represent data... The files are the same on each device... so to represent "123", perhaps I would play "abc" on the first device...

Comment: I think you need to give some more details about your application. How are these files looking like. Is it one single note per file, which is already truncated so there is no other stuff happening in there? Are there chords played inside a file? Depending on these factors you may also need to do onset detection etc. Otherwise you could go for relatively simple signal-processing approaches, like a frequency analysis.

Comment: @lmNt - The purpose of the sound files is to transmit data, so I'm open to any suggestion of what the audio file should sound like. I'm not trying to "recognise" sounds / notes for the sake of recognising notes. I want to use audio to transmit data. For example, just like binary is a set {0,1}, I am open to suggestions of what the sound files should sound like, since the goal is to transmit data using sound.

Comment: This is called matched filtering—it’s the backbone of radar and digital communications. I’m a little sad I can’t readily find an example online showing how it works using audio, here’s an explanation using [Matlab](http://archive.cnx.org/contents/85689497-f515-4124-8c9d-6dd4cb04bafe@3/birdcall-identification-matched-filter-implementation). Basically you matched-filter your audio against each of your files, and whichever gives you the highest peak, that’s the target signal. Recommend prototyping with [Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html)

Comment: Provide some test data? Should be five lines of Python with Numpy/Scipy.

Comment: @AhmedFasih Your link looks like what I'm trying to do - but in the bird call example, each bird will make sounds slightly different from the library of files right ? But in my case, since the library of sound files is the same on both devices, the sounds made by each device will be exactly the same! I imagine, there must be some way to optimise this then? Do you see what I mean ? I don't know how to use scipy or python (I use C++, Obj-c, java etc), but If you understand what I mean, then you won't need any test data - Imagine two devices with the same five files (a,b,c,d,e)...

Comment: @AhmedFasih If the first device plays the files "c,b,a", then I want the second device the recognise "c,b,a". The actual files / sounds can be whatever YOU think would be easiest to recognise ? You see what I mean ? The purpose is to transmit data between two devices by using the same library of sounds to represent the data...

Comment: Ok got it, you want to make an acoustic modem then. I’ve always wanted to implement this, and I’ll try to get to it soon but if I can’t, then, here’s the answer to your question—yes, I can see why you might think that, since the sound played and immediately recorded (presumably by a mic somewhere nearby) that you can do better than matched filtering, but your recorded samples won’t be bit-exact with the transmission, meaning you’ll have *noise*. And under noise, matched filter is king—that’s why it rules radar & digita comm (which is what you’re making, a digital comm system ).

Comment: The sounds themselves—comm systems like GSM, LTE, or Wifi are specified by many things including the waveforms they will use. The simplest waveforms, for e.g. an alphabet of eight, would probably be eight tones: pure sine waves at different frequencies. (No real comm system would use this because multiple users can’t share the same band, but for your purposes this doesn’t matter.)

Answer (score 1):

For very short sounds, matched filtering might work.  For anything longer (music?), search using the term "sound fingerprinting" or "music fingerprinting", which might involve learning about extracting and matching MFCC feature vectors.

Added: If you can make up your sounds for sending data, then look up the protocols that acoustic data modems used over phone lines.  300 to 1200 baud using FSK or QPSK, etc. Or higher data rates depending on S/N ratio and the acoustic environment (reliable bandwidth) between units.

Comment: I'm not trying to figure out anything about random sounds or music. I want to use sound to transmit data - so I am free to create the various sound files in advance. I don't know which kinds of sounds are distinctive and easily recognisable, so I am open to suggestions on what the sounds should be like so that I can recognise them easily. I am just trying to use sound to transmit data..